# Crazy xhr error

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

[image: Crazy xhr error]

Also on the server side error_log:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  theid in /.../postsForExtension.php on line 27
```

That code:

```
$personid = strip_tags($_POST['theid']);

Note: $personid is true.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think `xhr.responsetext` contains valid JSON.  So `JSON.parse` vomits up a syntax error.

What's your JSON response look like?

Comment: I forgot to use set
`xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); //following w3` and turn off error_reporting server side

Comment: @Devin: There is another problem, theid is not set within whatever data your posting, so there is part of the problem. You should ALSO fix that. Never use undefined anything.